# A java app only works when I do not include its".jar" extension in the command line, why is that so?

Tags: command-line, java, jar

I have been given a jar file to run it like this:

> java -jar app-versions-name.jar -settings ...(and some more arguments)

However, it does not work, stating the file cannot be found. But when I remove the jar extension from the command line, it works:

> java -jar app-versions-name -settings ...(and some more arguments)

Why is that so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your file doesn't have the extension and is called simply `app-versions-name`.

Therefore `java -jar app-versions-name` works because it runs the file called `app-versions-name`, while `java -jar app-versions-name.jar` says that file cannot be found because `app-versions-name.jar` doesn't exist.

There's nothing special about extensions nowadays, they're just a file naming convention we've adopted to make file types quickly identifiable. Removing them won't usually break things, because programs are working with file contents, not names.